# warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1\build\wx291_msw_vc10\..\..\lib\vc_lib\wxregex.lib) does not match

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

I get many warnings like these:

> C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1151,5):
>   warning MSB8012:
>   TargetPath(C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1\build\wx291_msw_vc10....\lib\vc_lib\wxregex.lib)
>   does not match the Linker's OutputFile
>   property value
>   (`C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1\lib\vc_lib\wxregexud.lib`).This may cause your project to build
>   incorrectly. To correct this, please
>   make sure that $(OutDir),
>   $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt)
>   property values match the value
>   specified in %(Link.OutputFile).

How i solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by selecting **Properties** for each failing project in the solution and then replacing **Configuration Properties -> General -> *Target Name*** to the name from **Configuration Properties -> Librarian (Linker) -> General -> *Output file*** field. I believe reverse method should work too by setting latter to ***<inherit from parent or project defaults>*** though I don't recommend it because all configurations will produce the same output.

For example:
**Librarian -> General -> *Output file*** = `..\..\lib\vc_lib\wxmsw29u_core.lib`
**General -> *Target Name*** = `wxmsw29u_core`

Answer (score -1):

The `u` and `d` in `wxregexud.lib` indicate Unicode build and Debug build. `wxregex.lib` is a non-Unicode non-debug built lib.

`C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1\lib\vc_lib\wxregexud.lib` is the normal place where libs are. For some reason your target path is incorrect.

Comment: Please do not muck around with the compiler/linker options in the library build projects.  You could easily make things worse, and no-one will know what is going on.  To select the build ( e.g. unicode release ) change the 'solution configuration' to the one you need.  This will adjust all those tricky compiler/linker option automatically o the ones you need for the selected build.

Comment: I never said to change the options in the library build projects! I meant in the project that is using wxWidgets, set those options to include the correct libs (unicode, debug, etc.), but I realize now that the error in question was about initially building the wxWidgets libs.